# How to Update the Register and Login links on ASPNET Core 6 Identity pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.NET Core 6.0 identity. All the identity pages are working fine, except the "Register" and "Login" at the top right of the pages.

When I login as a user, the "Register" link is replaced with "Hello" and the email of the logged in user and the "Login" link is replaced with the "Logout" link.

When I close the browser and run the site again, the login page is displayed correctly. However, at the top it still says "Hello" and the email of the previously logged in user and "Logout". Instead, I would like it to say "Register" and "Login".

These two links come from the `_Layout.cshtml` page in the shared folder. On the Login page's `OnGetAsync` method, I tried to put the following line of code:

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
```

Still it didn't get fixed. On the Google search, I learnt the authentication cookie may be persistent. When I checked the code, it was as shown below.

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, info.LoginProvider);
```

As you can see, it has `isPersistent: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is normal. When you close your browser, Project don't know if you want to logout, So when you open it again, authentication cookie is still in your browser, It will show you have logged in. That's how session-lifetime cookies work in the browser, that's not something the server has any control over.

If you want to achieve logout after you close browser tab, You can use javascript to achieve it, Please refer to this simple demo:

Create a logout action

```
public async Task Logout()
{
     await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
}
```

create a javascript in `_Layout.cshtml`, Use beforeunload event to send ajax to logout action when the browser tab close

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
            fetch('/home/Logout', {
                method: 'Get',            
            })        
        })
    </script>
```

Gif Demo:

[image]